# How can I get video from file Explorer

Tags: android

[image] I developed android application about video saving and play it from phone storage. I saved it but I don't get it and I don't save it. I shared photo location in below how can I get it and play it? I tried like below but I don't do it.

```
    SDCardRoot = new File(getFilesDir() + "/videos");![picture shows video location][2]

    File[] videos = SDCardRoot.listFiles();

    try {

        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(videos[1]);
        Log.i("fii", "" + fi);

        MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer();
        pl.setDataSource(fi.getFD());
        pl.prepare();
        pl.start();
```

Comment: What's the problem?
Are you unable to access the file?
Are you unable to play the file?

Comment: I don't know, how can I parse it? and after parse it I will play it

Comment: added some logs, or debug the code

Comment: I did, I get this from videos[1]= /data/data/com.example.downlaodvideo/files/videos/blaa.mp4

Comment: i added the code to play the video

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView vv;
vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
vv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sUriPath);
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(MainActivity.this));
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers as it's often not obvious as to how your code works. Please try to accompany your code with an explaination